Website is accessible via curl/ping, but not via browser
I have a server configured only for port HTTP 80.
Port 443 is disabled on my server.
Domain name - "eugenetree.dev"
As I thought, when I would open my site - the browser would check that there is no "443" port enabled and try to connect to port 80. However now, I just get an error that "This site can’t be reached".
Are there any docs somewhere regarding requirements from browser (particularly Chrome) in terms of how they handle such cases?

nginx config:


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name eugenetree.dev;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}



server running on port 3000


const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('<h1>test</h1>')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})




For starters: what webserver are you using?

Default nginx configuration. When I do curl I receive Welcome to nginx! in the response.

Can you edit your question and add the content of the conf file?

I've updated, thanks.

Did Bastiaan Wakkie's answer help you?

Partially, still want to investigate the underlying implementation in Chrome of what's going on when the 443 port is disabled.

Why isn't the webserver's setting enough and what would you like Chrome to do?

I'm just learning all the stuff related to basic of network, DNS, HTTP(S) and so on.
I've seen on some websites that uses HTTP - Chrome shows warning that "your connection is not private". And you're allowed to skip this warning and proceed to the website. But in my case - I can't get this warning using https://eugenetree.dev. I just receive ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. The only option for now how I can open my site is using http://164.92.198.224/.

In nginx you need to (permanently?) redirect 443 to 80.
If you access via a browser does it use https by default?
server {  # HTTPs -->    HTTP
        server_name             .eugenetree.dev;
        listen 443 default_server;
        return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
}


Is it required configuration? I thought the browser would try to connect to 443 port and if the 443 port is disabled or unavailable because of some other reasons - it would connect to 80.
I tried to find some related docs on chrome forums but with no success, unfortunately. Is this information available somewhere?

This is generally always the case. port 80 and port 443 are who different things, could even be two different sites. But these days we redirect all :80 traffic first to :443 and move on from there. You want the opposite though.
